# How to update a variable inside the useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-hooks

I have the following state

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  myForm: "",
});
```

after some operation I am able to update the formData but how can I update the state to clear the input field after submitting so that the value that I entered after validation disappear?

I am using material UI

```js
function handleFormChange(event: any) {
  let data: any = formData;
  data[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  setFormData(data);
  console.log(data);
}
```

with this method I am able to console log every time I change the input field of course and with that to handle the submit of the form

```js
const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (...) { //if myform is validated
    //clear the input field here
  ;
```

```
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="add-form">
      <TextField
        name="myForm"
        label="Enter Value"
       
        onChange={handleFormChange}
        defaultValue={""}
       
      />

      <Button
        type="submit"
        name="add-button"
        disabled={!buttonDisable}
        onClick={() => {
          validate;
        }}
      >
        Add
      </Button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hello, the question is a little unclear. What do you mean by _update the state to unclear the input field after submitting_? If you may clearly explain the problem, and the expected result, you will get better answers.

Comment: Hi I edited the question you´re right. I want to clear the input field after submitting the form

Comment: So, `setFormData({ myForm: "" })` doesn't work for you? Or if you've other nested state, `setFormData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, myForm: "" }));`. What exactly are you wanting to clear upon form submission? Are you basically wanting to reset a form?

Comment: @DrewReese yes basically I want to clear the form after submitting it ,I tried also setFormData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, myForm: "" })); but is not working

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what your code is doing? If you could also include a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we could live inspect and debug that would be helpful.

Comment: @DrewReese I put also the html code , I tried to put the setForm data also in the validate() function but still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `defaultValue` prop you are technically using an uncontrolled input.

You can:

1. Keep the input uncontrolled and clear the input's value via the form's `onSubmit` event.

   ```
   const handleSubmit = e => {
     e.preventDefault();

     e.target.myForm.value = ''; // <-- clear input's value
     ...
   }
   ```

   You can also call `e.target.reset();` to simply reset the entire form.
2. Convert it to a controlled input and clear the value in state.

   ```
   const handleSubmit = e => {
     e.preventDefault();

     setFormData(formData => ({
       ...formData,
       myForm: '', // <-- clear upon submission
     }));
     ...
   }

   ...

   <TextField
     name="myForm"
     label="Enter Value"
     onChange={handleFormChange}
     value={formData.myForm} // <-- use value attribute
   />
   ```

Additionally, you probably don't want to mix an `onClick` handler on a form submit button. Do the field validation in the submit handler.

Comment: @javaFE Just added a note that you can also call `e.target.reset();` to reset the entire form versus setting a specific field's value. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but you can do the following way to do unclear input after submit the form data.

```
const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (...) { //if myform is validated
    //clear the input field here
    let tempFormData = {...formData};
    tempFormData.myForm = "";
    setFormData(tempFormData);
}
```

Comment: this make sense and I tried something similar so set it to an empty string and then update the state but after I submit the input field is still not cleared